# Creating Apple Music developer token

Tags: ios, xcode, jwt, apple-musickit

I'm trying to create a JWT with JWT.io for Apple Music api (ObjC) and for some reason it's not generating a token when I follow the format Apple says to do in documentation using (ES256). Does anyone know how to set up Apple Music api tokens for xcode?

Answer (score 7):

You first have to create a MusicKit identifier and a private key using [this guide from Apple](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devce5522674). Then a token can be easily created using [Swift-JWT from IBM](https://ibm-swift.github.io/Swift-JWT/) in pure Swift.

It's more or less just an invocation of the SwiftJWT API:

```
let teamId = "yourTeamID"
let keyId = "yourKeyID"
let keyFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/pathToYour/key.p8")

struct MyClaims: Claims {
    let iss: String
    let iat: Date?
    let exp: Date?
}

let myHeader = Header(kid: keyId)
let myClaims = MyClaims(iss: teamId, iat: Date(), exp: Date() +  24 * 60 * 60)
var myJWT = SwiftJWT.JWT(header: myHeader, claims: myClaims)

let token = try! myJWT.sign(using: .es256(privateKey: try! String(contentsOf: keyFileUrl).data(using: .utf8)!))
```

I created a simple example and a command line tool using the Swift Package Manager: [SwiftJWTSample](https://github.com/klaas/SwiftJWTSample/)

Comment: Hello @Klaas Would you please specify that using the above code are you able to generate the User Token(Music Token) which is needed to fetch the personalised playlist and all.

The token generated using the above method work for the Catalogs service but always fails for the generation of UserToken.

Where as the token generated using the python script using (jeremyms answer) work well in both catalog services and the generation of usertoken.

Comment: @SULEMANBAWA I haven't needed that yet, but I'll put it on my list to try it.

Comment: Great answer! But the repo link in the answer is expired, you can find the new Swift-JWT repo [here](https://github.com/Kitura/Swift-JWT)

Answer (score 5):

There are current 3rd party tools available for creating an Apple Music developer token (for example: https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator). Try using one of those to see if that works.

Comment: I remember having trouble creating a valid JWT. This^ was the one that worked for me.